# Using Libraries with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I am currently using Android Stuio Beta 0.8.1 an its working fine but I am having an issue with library projects are handled.

In Eclipse, I create an Android project which is my app project and another project which is my Library project. From my App project, I reference my Library Project and I can modify the library project and the changes are automatically built into the app project.

I am trying to do the same thing with Android studio but am having a problem.

The problem is I create my Library project in Android Studio and my App Project in Android Studio.

From my app project I go File > Import Module and point to my library project and it then copies all of the source code from my library project into my apps project structure.

From my app project I then project structure and select module dependency of the module I have just imported.

The problem is though, as it copies all of the source from my library project into my app project, if I modify the code that's imported into the app project structure, then the library project isn't updated, and if I update the library project code, the app referencing the library doesn't see the change.

My library is being referenced by multiple projects, and at the moment if I change, librar projects, the apps continue to use the old code, so I am having to copy/paste the source code into the apps project stucture and re-build.

Am I missing something basic or is it just Android Studio isn't really working too well witih libraries so copy/paste is my only option for the time being.

Comment: I've seen some people use git submodules to share library alike code between projects. Don't have experience to tell how well they perform at the end though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because libraries must live within the main project, it's difficult to share them across projects. If that's your usage, the library should be its own project that you [publish to maven locally](https://www.flexlabs.org/2013/06/using-local-aar-android-library-packages-in-gradle-builds). After that, you can declare it as a dependency similar to any other. Keep in mind that the version number of the library becomes important; when you make changes to the library, be sure to publish with a new version number.

Comment: OK will take a look at this and let you know. It seems a bit odd that library projects aren't easily shared between projects as that's the whole purpose of a library

Comment: Cheers, this has worked, I'm having problems doing the automatic maven publishing, but I have at least got it maven and successfully reference the project.